# How to copy the web site contents into the docker container from controller machine using ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I was working to deploy a docker container with a simple web files and wrote following Ansible script for configure and deploy the docker container with creating a docker network. I am able to access the docker container from the network but I was not able to manage copying the website to the container.
following is the my Ansible script and other scripts. I was trying with different approaches but was not able to make it fix.

```
- name: Deploy Apache Docker Container
  hosts: docker_hosts  
  #connection: remote
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Install Docker dependencies
      apt:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      loop:
        - apt-transport-https
        - ca-certificates
        - curl
        - gnupg
        - lsb-release

    - name: Add Docker's official GPG key
      apt_key:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
        state: present

    - name: Add Docker repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} stable
        state: present

    - name: Update apt packages cache
      apt:
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Install Docker
      apt:
        name: docker-ce
        state: present

    - name: Start Docker service
      service:
        name: docker
        state: started

    #Install Docker python package which is already not installed
    - name: Install Docker Python package
      apt:
        name: python3-docker
        state: present
    # Creates docker network with /30 subnet mask
    - name: Set up container to run on 172.168.11.0/30 subnet
      docker_network:
        name: 20024471_B9IS121-network
        ipam_config:
          - subnet: "172.168.11.0/30"
        
    # Pulls the latest docker image with Apache web server.
    - name: Pull Apache Docker image
      docker_image:
        name: httpd
        tag: latest
        source: pull

    # Defines the list of container configurations to add to the docker network
    # In this case, second IP is automatically assign to the bridge network between 
    # docker host computer and the containers. this is a limitation.
    - name: Define list of container configurations
      set_fact:
        container_configs:
          - name: 20024471_B9IS121-container-1
            image: httpd:latest
            # add website directory to htdocs on the container
            volumes:
              - "{{ playbook_dir }}/myweb:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
            ports:
              - "8080:80"
            networks:
              - name: 20024471_B9IS121-network
                ipv4_address: 172.168.11.2
            networks_cli_compatible: yes
            container_default_behavior: compatibility
            network_mode: default               
    
          # increase the subnet to enable more containers if required.
          # uncomment following under -name to configure more containers.
          #- name: 20024471_B9IS121-container-2
          #  image: httpd:latest
          #  volumes:
          #    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/myweb:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
          #  ports:
          #    - "8081:80"
          #  networks:
          #    - name: 20024471_B9IS121-network
          #      ipv4_address: 172.168.10.3
          #  networks_cli_compatible: yes
          #  container_default_behavior: compatibility
          #  network_mode: default

    # iterate the list of containers and create the containers
    - name: deploy an Apache Docker container
      docker_container:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        image: "{{ item.image }}"
        volumes: "{{ item.volumes }}"
        ports: "{{ item.ports }}"
        networks: "{{ item.networks }}"
        networks_cli_compatible: "{{ item.networks_cli_compatible }}"
        container_default_behavior: "{{ item.container_default_behavior }}"
        network_mode: "{{ item.network_mode }}"
      loop: "{{ container_configs }}"

    - name: Print playbook directory
      debug:
        var: playbook_dir
```

the inventory.ini file

```
[docker_hosts]
#host1 ansible_host=192.168.18.22
host1 ansible_host=192.168.122.192 ansible_user=kala ansible_password=kalabara
#192.168.122.192
```

Output when running the ansible-plabook

```
# ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini docker_deploy.yml --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 

PLAY [Deploy Apache Docker Container] ****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Install Docker dependencies] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=apt-transport-https)
ok: [host1] => (item=ca-certificates)
ok: [host1] => (item=curl)
ok: [host1] => (item=gnupg)
ok: [host1] => (item=lsb-release)

TASK [Add Docker's official GPG key] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Add Docker repository] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Update apt packages cache] *********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]

TASK [Install Docker] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Start Docker service] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Install Docker Python package] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Set up container to run on 172.168.11.0/30 subnet] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Pull Apache Docker image] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [Define list of container configurations] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]

TASK [deploy an Apache Docker container] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item={'name': '20024471_B9IS121-container-1', 'image': 'httpd:latest', 'volumes': ['/home/nishshanka/Documents/20024471_B9IS121_2324_TMD2_NETWORKS_SYSTEMS_ADM/myweb:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs'], 'ports': ['8080:80'], 'networks': [{'name': '20024471_B9IS121-network', 'ipv4_address': '172.168.11.2'}], 'networks_cli_compatible': True, 'container_default_behavior': 'compatibility', 'network_mode': 'default'})

TASK [Print playbook directory] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "playbook_dir": "/home/username/Documents/20024471_B9IS121_2324_TMD2_NETWORKS_SYSTEMS_ADM"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=13   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```